# Post JSON in DynamoDB via Lambda

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have trouble storing a JSON file in my DynamoDB table with the help of my Lambda function and my API Gateway on AWS. I have the following piece of code which gets executed once I press a button on my HTML site:

```
  $('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var example = {"number":"121212"};

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: API_URL,
      data: JSON.stringify(example),
      contentType: "application/json",

      success: function(data){
        location.reload();
        }
    });

    return false;
  });
```

When pressed the website reloads, hence I assume function has successfully executed. However my problem is that the data does not arrive in the correct format in the lambda function and hence does not execute properly. When checking in CloudWatch it is shown as { number: '121212' } instead of {"number":"121212"}. Any idea how I can make sure that the value 'arrives' has a valid JSON format in my Lambda function?

Here's my Lambda function:

```
exports.handler = function index(e, ctx, callback) {
    var params = {
        Item: { number: e.number },
        TableName: 'collectionOfNumbers'
    };
    docCLient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The  { number: '121212' } representation seems reasonable to me. How are you using this value in the Lambda function and what is going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the Lambda function, which I linked to the post method of my API Gateway (I omitted the docClient and the AWS-sdk due to char limit). Essentially it doesn't write the value in the db.

exports.handler = function index(e, ctx, callback){

    var params = {
        Item: {
            number: e.number
        },
        
        TableName: 'collectionOfNumbers'
    };
    
    docCLient.put(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
    
}

Comment: Are you saying that the put() call succeeds but you see no evidence in the DynamoDB table that an item was written? Any chance that you are simply overwriting an existing item, hence the number of items in the table does not change?

Comment: Also, CORS is enabled and I have given the vast read/write rights to the function in IAM

Comment: I think it don't even get to the put() call, because my CloudWatch gives me the following error (apologies, I should have mentioned this earlier): SyntaxError: Unexpected token o at Object.parse (native) at index (/var/task/index.js:10:22)

Comment: Please add some basic console.log() statements into your Lambda function then check CloudWatch Logs a minute or so after you test again. Verify if your Lambda function is being called and, if so, correlate the SyntaxError to your actual code to help you debug.

Comment: I think your error might actually be in your callback after docCLient.put. If you comment out everything but your instantiation of your params object in your lambda, do you still get that CloudWatch error?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, e.number is the value of the JSON parameter 'number' that you are passing in, e.g. '121212'. I'm making the assumption from the usage that docClient is putItem under the hood.

I think your Item param should look like:

```
Item: {"number": {N: e.number}}
```

See AWS Docs for info regarding PutItem https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've tried it, and I get the following error:  "One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key number expected: S actual: M",

Comment: That probably means that e.number is actually a map. Can you console log your event (e) and share the output?

Comment: Yes, now I get: "One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key number in the item". That is a bit strange, because I put the key of the DynamoDB in the name?

Comment: It would really be helpful to see what is actually being passed from API Gateway to the Lambda, or at least a console log of what e contains. I am suspecting that something has been mapped in a weird way.